# Generate CSV from NS Zone File

Tags: regex, csv, perl, awk

I have a large file that contains records in multilines.
ex:

```
domain1 NS ns1
domain1 NS ns2
domain1 NS ns3
domain2 NS dnsx
```

What might be the fastest way to generate a CSV of the form

```
domain1,ns1,ns2,ns3
domain2, dnsx
```

I have tried php and groovy scripts but the processor load time is too high for a file (read) of a 1Gb file (and a consequent write to a csv file).

I am thinking there should be a better programatic approach than what I am doing. Basically I am creating a list/array to contain records and check against the last element if the same domain is found in the current line being checked.

P.S Mentioned groovy/php, but response may have no relation to these specific scripting languages.

Comment: Is the file already sorted by domain? Or at least, are all the records with the same domain grouped together?

Comment: They are sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the records with the same domain are grouped together, this awk program will have a very small memory footprint (can't say what the CPU load will be)

```
awk '
    $1 != domain {
        if (domain) print ""
        printf "%s", $1
        domain = $1
    } 
    {printf ",%s", $3} 
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Comment: Although CPU load hits 100, this is way much more effective than what I had! Thank you very much. 
Neet to tweak the script to read file arguments and is perfect!

P.S Seems the %s is not needed on line 7.

Comment: I always use a formatting string with printf. What if the $1 string itself contains a %s

Comment: It is just that it ends up in a fatal error: (FILENAME=net.zone2 FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
 `,%sNS1.'
   ^ ran out for this one

Comment: Oh! I forgot the comma after the format string.